# Manual sleep in char driver halts read() forever

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel-module

I am learning linux device drivers. I came across a topic 'manual sleep'. So I wrote a simple char driver in which the read method will sleep if no data is written into the buffer

The problem is the read method sleeps forever even if data has been written

What can be the possible error in the code?
Thanks in advance for any help.

the code snippets from the char driver are

```
wait_queue_head_t q;
wait_queue_t wait;
int major_no, flag=0;
char device_buffer[100];

ssize_t myread(struct file *p, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *s)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "myread() method\n");
    prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if(flag!=1)
    {
        schedule();
    }
    copy_to_user(buf, device_buffer, strlen(device_buffer));
    flag=0;
    return 0;
}

ssize_t mywrite(struct file *p, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *s)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "mywrite() method\n");
    memset(device_buffer, 0, 100);
    copy_from_user(device_buffer, buf, len);
    flag=1;
    finish_wait(&q, &wait);
    printk("%s", device_buffer);
    return 0;
}

struct file_operations p={
    .open=myopen,
    .release=myclose,
    .write=mywrite,
    .read=myread
};

int start(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "module registered\n");
    memset(device_buffer, 0, 100);
    major_no=register_chrdev(0, "mydriver", &p);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "driver major no : %d\n", major_no);
    init_waitqueue_head(&q);
    init_wait(&wait);
    return 0;
}
```

The complete code for user-space app is

```
#include<fcntl.h>

main()
{
    char option, m[100];
    memset(m, 0, 100);
    int fd=open("my_dev_file", O_RDWR);
    printf("%d\n", fd);
    printf("read : r\nwrite : w\n");
    scanf("%c", &option);
    switch(option)
    {
            case 'w':
                    printf("msg : ");
                    scanf("%s", m);
                    write(fd, m, strlen(m));
                    break;
            case 'r':
                    read(fd, m, 100);
                    printf("msg = %s\n", m);
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("wrong choice\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the 'complete code for user space app'  doesn't even come close to cleanly compiling.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.  I normally also add: `-std-c99 -Wconversion`)  Then fix the resulting warnings.  For a start, when using an OS,  there are only 2 valid (and one optional) signatures for the main() function and they ALL have a return type of `int`

Comment: cont: the code is missing the required #include statements for the definition of `memset()`, `open()`, `printf()`, `scanf()`, `write()`, `read()`, `strlen()` and since `open()` was called, there should be a matching call to `close()` which the code is missing.

Comment: when calling the `open()` function, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   when calling the `scanf()` function, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  when calling the `read()` function, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Those header files are required just for prototypes and the prototypes arent mandetory for scanf, printf, memset and all...i can compile them with warnings but not errors....the executable file always works fine...why to include unnecessary header files to increse the program size

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers make the code difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  The 'magic' numbers include `100`.  Suggest using #define to give 'magic' numbers a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("read : r\nwrite : w\n");`  This output will have no intrinsic meaning to the user.  Suggest: "to read from the device, enter: 'r' to write to the device, enter: 'w' "

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s", m);`,  there is no max number of characters modifier to limit the user input length.  Therefore, the user can overflow the 'm[]' array.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest:  `scanf("%99s", m);` using 99 to allow for the scanf() automatically appending a NUL byte to any input performed via the '%s" format specification parameter.

Comment: Your suggestion matter a lot but I am not developing a commercial software...I am just learning device drivers and experimenting with these codes...I hope this code can be understood by people on stackoverflow...still I will rectify ...thanks

Comment: As I am the only one experimenting with this code i always give a string input of length less than 100....please suggest me what is the problem so that read() halts

Comment: The question seems to be a runtime problem.  For run time problems, the code needs to cleanly compile, the actual/representative input needs to be posted, the actual output needs to be posted the expected output needs to be posted.   Since the device driver does not compile (almost every line produces a warning or error) this question is off-topic until it is corrected

Comment: I have not posted the whole code....i wrote there that I am posting only some snippets of the char driver...my whole code includes all the header files and other methods and that code does not give a single warning...it is cleanly compiled

Comment: a call to `read()` ,in user space, will block until it sees EOF or the requested number of characters or a signal occurs.  In the current scenario, that is not the cause of the problem.   However, the posted character device driver seems to have several problems.  Suggest reading: <http://www.crashcourse.ca/introduction-linux-kernel-programming/lesson-17-your-first-character-device-driver> which goes into depth on how to design/write and prepare the OS for the character device driver.

Comment: the myread function must return the read bytes. see http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch03.html#t8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions `prepare_to_wait` and `finish_wait` **are part of single *wait***.

They **are not** `wait()` and `notify()` analogues of high-level languages such as java.

More correct waiting implementation could be:

```
// Global scope: no need to declare `wait`, it will be locally declared in *myread*

// myread
DEFINE_WAIT(wait); // this is a *declaration*, so it should come before function's call like `printk`.
prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
if(flag!=1)
{
    schedule();
}
finish_wait(&q, &wait); // This is *finalization* for waiting
...

// mywrite
flag = 1;
wake_up(&q);
```

Note, that this is *not a fully correct example*: at least, `flag` should be checked and set under some critical section, e.g. with spinlock held. But it just works in your simple scenario.

Alternatively, you may use *completion*:

```
// Global scope
#include <linux/completion.h>
DECLARE_COMPLETION(comp);

// myread
wait_for_completion_interruptible(&comp);

// mywrite
complete(&comp);
```

In this case completion will be automatically rearmed after waiting.